# How to upload Email Attachments using griddler and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, mandrill, griddler

I'm using [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) as Inbound email routing and I'm using those gems to receive emails and save it in a database.

- [griddler](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler)
- [griddler-mandrill](https://github.com/wingrunr21/griddler-mandrill)
- [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

How can I save the attachments in separated database table "`Attachments`" using paperclip.

Answer (score 1):

`Griddler::Email` has an `attachments` attribute, which is:

> An array of File objects containing any attachments.

So, if you have a model like this:

```
class Assessment
  has_attached_file :file
end
```

You would simply do, for example:

```
@email.attachments.each{|f| Attachment.create(file: f)}
```